# How to reset all tableView data and arrays when click of UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, reset

I have 1 tabbarcontroller have Login and Complete Tab. I want to click on Logout button in LoginTab, all data and tableview in COmplete tab is reset. I used this code but it not work:

In CompleteTab.m:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    iduploadArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    FileCompletedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    DiffArr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:FileCompletedArray,nil];
    // [_tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];
    //tableView.dataSource = self;
    // [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    // [self parseXMLFile:@"x"];

    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"server.com"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: url1] ;

        ....
        temp = [FileCompletedArray mutableCopy];

        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.delegate=self;

        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];

       }
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"error: %@", error);//: %@",  operation.responseString);

                                      }
     ];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

}

-(void) resetAll
{
    [temp removeAllObjects];
    [FileCompletedArray removeAllObjects];
    [DiffArr removeAllObjects];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

In LoginTab.m:

```
- (IBAction)LogoutButton:(id)sender {

    login = false;
    username.hidden = NO;
    pass.hidden = NO;

    LoginButton.hidden = NO;
    LogoutButton.hidden = YES;

    //make all the arrays get reset
    username.text =@"";
    pass.text = @"";
    [completeview resetAll];

}
```

I debug: when I click on Logout button,it called resetAll() function but each variable is 0x000000. So it cannot reset data and reload tableview. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Which variables are nil ?

Comment: All variables in CompleteTab are nil

Comment: Each tab is ViewController type

Comment: put all code of CompleteTab.m and LoginTab.m here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the logout button is in loginTab, it doesnot have any reference to your completeTab. So you need to keep the completeTab reference some where in your app. Best choice is in appDelegate. Then on logout button click, take this instance and reset all data.

Keep your completab view controller instance in AppDelegate like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *completeTab;

self.completeTab = \\Your complete tab viewcontroller instance.
```

Then on logout button click

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].completTab resetAll]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector to call the reset method like this

```
[completeview performSelector:@selector(resetAll)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please create sample project with Tabbased Application.

**======  AppDelegate.m ======**

```
#import "LoginTab.h"

#import "CompleteTab.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[LoginTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginTab" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[CompleteTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompleteTab" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**======  LoginTab.m ======**

```
@implementation LoginTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"LoginTab", @"LoginTab");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginTab"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)LogoutButton:(id)sender {

    // Post Notification to CompleteTab Class

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"resetAll"
     object:self];

}
```

**======  CompleteTab.m ======**

```
@implementation CompleteTab

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"CompleteTab", @"CompleteTab");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CompleteTab"];
    }


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(resetAll:)
                                                 name:@"resetAll"
                                               object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) resetAll:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Reset All Called");
}
```

I am able to call resetAll method of CompeteTab using NSNotification Concept. Please follow this code.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but it not reset tableview and array.

Comment: It still nil for all variables in CompletedTab

Comment: always retain your tableview and array which you are using.

Comment: How can i do If i want removeallObject in array and reload tableview in completedTab when click on Logout Button in Logintab???

Comment: please post your project code somewhere and i will make changes and get back to you.

Comment: Do you have email ?What's your email? I'll send code to you by email

Comment: I sent mail to you. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework as it has such restting functionality out of box.

Answer (score 0):

As for the method [tableView reloadData] :  The table view's delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within a block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates.
I believe you are calling the reloadData in resetAll which is updating the FileCompletedArray which provides the dataSource for the table. Can you call it from somewhere else.